# Would an increase in VRAM for my integrated graphics card affect my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I have 4GB RAM on my laptop and I'd like to allocate the amount of RAM I read on this article for 4GB RAM(here's the link:https://appuals.com/how-to-increase-intel-graphics-dedicated-video-memory/) Would this increase in VRAM for my integrated graphics card affect my laptop's performance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, broadly, yes - but it depends on what you're going to do with it as to how badly you will be affected.

You only have 4GB RAM to start with. That's tiny by today's standards & your OS is going to need maybe half of that to even run.
Windows tends to start paging back to HD once you're over half your RAM - so it's going to be doing that pretty much from boot.
If you then take another 512MB away from your usable total, you're leaving maybe 1.5 GB to work in. That could be as little as half a dozen web tabs in a browser.
The more you take from your overall, the more the OS will page, the slower your experience will be.

So, yes, it will affect it. To see how much, you'll just have to try it & see.

Comment: Oh ok, that's good to know. Cause my main motivation for doing this is because I'm getting a lot of lag in some games even if I fully reach the minimum requirements like starcraft 2 and hearthstone to mention a few and sometimes in general too so I thought it would help (here's laptop specs for reference: HP Notebook 15, 4GB RAM,1 TB HDD, Intel i5-8250 1.6 GHz)

Comment: That's the thing about 'minimum spec' - it really is the absolute bare minimum required for the game to run, it's nowhere near sufficient for it to run **well**.

Comment: https://trickiknow.com/hp-notebook-15-ram-upgrade-tutorial-very-easy/ shows how to upgrade your memory, and what memory you need to buy - DDR4 either 4GB or 8GB.